# Ansible group sets of servers into 'apps'

Tags: ansible

I have a script that setups all the servers. Now trying to figure out a good way to configure them to talk to each other. e.g. Configure the application server to talk to a particular database server.

- Test app 1

  - db01
  - app01
  - app02
  - mem01
- Test app 2

  - db02
  - app03
  - mem02

The only thing I could come up with a role that takes the servers as params but I dislike that I have to also specify the hosts twice.

```
- name: Test app 1
  hosts: [db01, app01, app02, mem01]
  roles:
    - {role: app, db: db01, ap: [app01, app02], mem: mem01}
```

Comment: Could you expland more on "configure them to talk to each other"? What goal would require ansible be used for such a purpose?

Answer (score 0):

How organized is your [inventory file](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html)?

Looking at what you posted, this might be a good inventory file organization for you:

```
[testapp1-dbServers]
db01

[testapp1-appServers]
app01
app02

[testapp1-memServers]
mem01

[testapp2-dbServers]
db02

[testapp2-appServers]
app03

[testapp2-memServers]
mem02

[testapp1:children]
testapp1-dbServers
testapp1-appServers
testapp1-memServers

[testapp2:children]
testapp2-dbServers
testapp2-appServers
testapp2-memServers

[dbServers:children]
testapp1-dbServers
testapp2-dbServers

[appServers:children]
testapp1-appServers
testapp2-appServers

[memServers:children]
testapp1-memServers
testapp2-memServers
```

This might be overkill if you have no plans to increase the number of servers in any of the first 6 buckets, but it allows you to do things like group_vars files (individual ones for some or all groupings - testapp1, testapp2, dbServers, etc) and clean up your playbook file:

```
- name: Test app 1
  hosts: testapp1 (all vars passed via group_vars file)
  roles:
    - generic_server_setup

- name: DB Server setup
  hosts: dbServers (all vars passed via group_vars file)
  roles:
    - install_postgres
    - other_db_things
```

The final thing that will help you the most can be found [here](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).

Specifically, getting access to all the groups the current host is in and all the hosts in a group.

QUICK FIX: If you want to sacrifice some organization because you aren't worried about scaling and are not annoyed by the same information being in multiple locations, just add the relevant hosts as vars to testapp1 and testapp2 files under group_vars.